# Using proc tabulate to arrange the table in a certain way, need some assistance

Tags: statistics, sas

I tried using the proc tabulate to format the table in such a way that would look exactly like this output (see image)
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgIYW.png)

However i have this output showing up along with my code.
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i7x6.png)

Here is my sample code

```
data cutepets;
input gender $ type$ numpets;
datalines;
boy  cockatiel 1
boy  turtle    3
boy  rabbit    4
girl cockatiel 2
girl turtle    3
girl rabbit    7
;
proc format;
value $cutjpegs
    'Cockatiel'='//vdi-fileshare01/UEMprofiles/029946759/Desktop/Cockatiel.jpg'
;
value color
'type' = 'green';
run;
proc tabulate data = cutepets;
class type  gender;
classlev type / s=[background=$color. postimage=$cutjpegs. cellwidth=80];
var numpets ;
table gender* numpets = ' ', type = ' '
sum = ' '
/ rts=25 row=float
 box={label='# of pets'}
;

run;
```

If theres any pointers for me to know that would be greatly appreciated.

I almost have the jpegs ready to be placed however i am still struggling with formatting correctly. the online sources i was referred to were very helpful but for whatever reason when i apply their same methodology it doesnt work for me.

Comment: What type of output file are you creating? HTML? PDF? Something else?

Comment: Its for an assignment actually, so typically ill use the snipping tool to screencap the output and put it into a word document then convert it to a PDF file per instructions

Comment: Are the *type* images in a standard location that can be accessed by the output?  ODS PDF will create a pdf so you won't have to capture and paste.  Take a look at Example 10 in the classic "PROC TABULATE: Doin’ It in Style!" https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/085-29.pdf, SUGI 29, Ray Pass and Sandy McNeill

Comment: The images are stored on my desktop. I used proc format to see if i can call upon the jpegs in the styling but i just cant get it to work. my post was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is StackOverflow. And I know Stack Overflow prefers "the code" over "links" but! since it is a "home work" (and homework should educate) lets do it like this:

- Here is the link to a particular part of `Proc tabulate` [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1g617vn5t3p39n0z9o601rw74jz.htm#p1t0en9wtu0unmn1lpmc8s3oyegm). Read here about "*Labels*" and see the example there "[Eliminating Row Headings](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n0fvrniil70dmin1r4keedcrilo0.htm#n0fvrniil70dmin1r4keedcrilo0)"

Comment: Thank you so much for the references. they have been incredibly helpful. I updated my post with the most recent thing i am struggling on. I cant seem to get the code from the reference base applied correctly to my own.

Comment: The problem is not with `proc tabulate` but wth your `input` statement, `type$` sets length of `type` variable to 8 bytes (which is default setting)... and cuts letter from "cockatiel". Use this: `input gender $ type: $ 10. numpets;` and go and get some reading about the `input` statement: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lestmtsref/n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm Read this and 4 consecutive chapters.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, with the assistance of @marc_s and @yabwon i figured out that the images that were needed were correct with the syntax HOWEVER the original file was NOT capitalized. for instance.

```html
proc format;
value $cutjpegs
    'cockatiel'='\\vdi-fileshare01\UEMprofiles\029946759\Desktop\cockatiel.jpg'
    'rabbit'='\\vdi-fileshare01\UEMprofiles\029946759\Desktop\rabbit.jpg'
    'turtle'='\\vdi-fileshare01\UEMprofiles\029946759\Desktop\turtle.jpg'
;
```

compared to

```
'Cockatiel'='//vdi-fileshare01/UEMprofiles/029946759/Desktop/Cockatiel.jpg'
```

... etc

## In regards to input

```
input gender $ type: $ 10. numpets;
```

needed to be corrected and that solved most of the problems i had

## In regards to color

```
 class {variable} / s={background=color foreground=color postimage=$cutjpegs.}
```

This seemed to have made things appear more colorful and more to the format I was looking for.

Comment: I know the INPUT statements allows you to put a space after the $ but in normal usage the $ is part of the informat specification.  So adding that extra space just makes your code LOOK wrong, like you are trying to use the numeric informat 10. with a character variable.  Also I would leave a space before the : modifier so that it does not look like you are trying the name the variable type: instead of type.

Comment: Hey @Tom, it is my bad , I shared that code with Ryan. Out of a bad habit I'm mixing the "column input" (`x $ 1-10`) with "formatted input" (`x $10.`). It's not that easy to root it out :-) :-)